# Cannot find name 'require'. ANGULAR 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, require

I have an angular2 app where I need to use a payment API.

https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart

In this code sample on the nodejs section they say to use it like this:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
var token = request.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

// Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

We installed requireJS with NPM, however when we run it we get this error:

> Cannot find name 'require'.
>
> ```
>   L48:    pagar() {
>   L49:      var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_ayzCMDmjq2QOIW0s3dTihxNR");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
import * as stripe from "stripe";

public stripeKey = stripe("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");
```

Comment: It looks like that solved the require issue, however now I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).createServer is not a function